# How to detect if Parse app is in Production mode?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

So most Cloud modules require a api key that is in most cases different for production and development environment.

Is there a JS API call for detecting if app is running in development or in production so right keys can be used?

Comment: Had the same problem... I eventually used a 'isDebug' variable to indicate whether I'm on prod or not.. it's hacky, inconvenient, and not safe for use, but that's the only solution I could find.

Comment: Yes that's is one solution. But clearly not practical. Other way would be to use Parse.Config but its async and slow.